# Unable to ping pc from any other pcs

Tags: windows-8

I am unable to ping my pc from any other pc's on the network. There is no issue on firewall or any antivirus. I tried by disabling both also but no positive result.

Comment: Are you using a mobile hotspot from an Android phone?

Comment: No,I never used.

Comment: What does "Media Sense" tell you?  (Is the link up?)  What are your IP address settings (your IP address, your subnet size/prefix length/subnet mask, default gateway, and the IP address that you are trying to ping)?

Comment: My Ip address is 192.168.1.109,I am trying to ping to "192.168.1.105".I can ping by host name to same pc.Subnet mask-255.255.255.0.Default Gateway-192.168.1.1.Wifi network is using

Comment: I can ping using ipv6 address,which is set automatically.and I am unable to ping with ipv4.

Comment: What router do you have